# Batch script to detect and check log files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

Our system generates some random log files with stamp of date and time every 15 minutes on daily basis as shown on below listing. There are a lot of files generated in a day as the frequency is 15 minutes and it's a headache to check them 1 by 1.

```
LOG_20150118210000.txt
LOG_20150118211501.txt
LOG_20150118213000.txt
LOG_20150118214501.txt
LOG_20150118220000.txt
LOG_20150118221500.txt
LOG_20150118223000.txt
LOG_20150118224500.txt
LOG_20150118230001.txt
LOG_20150118231500.txt
LOG_20150118233001.txt
LOG_20150118234500.txt
LOG_20150119000001.txt
LOG_20150119001500.txt
LOG_20150119003001.txt
LOG_20150119004500.txt
LOG_20150119010000.txt
LOG_20150119011501.txt
LOG_20150119013000.txt
LOG_20150119014501.txt
LOG_20150119020000.txt
LOG_20150119021500.txt
LOG_20150119023000.txt
LOG_20150119024500.txt
LOG_20150119030000.txt
LOG_20150119031501.txt
```

Sample of missing files (5 files):

```
LOG_20150118233001.txt
LOG_20150118234500.txt
LOG_20150119000001.txt
LOG_20150119001500.txt
LOG_20150119003001.txt
```

How to write dos batch script to check and detect those missing files based on current date? Will it possible to check how many files are missing?

---

Results from Stephan's code:

Thank you for your reply and help.

I've tried your script and here is the output:

```
D:\temp>test1.bat
File Not Found
expected files:

---------- SHOULD.TXT: 2976

found files:

---------- IS.TXT: 0

these files are missing:
FINDSTR: No search strings
```

Could you help to let me know what does this output mean?

For testing, I've deleted 1 file and could not see the script has detected it.

---

Here are some sample logs, no point in listing all of them:

```
LOG_20150119000001.txt
LOG_20150119001500.txt
LOG_20150119003001.txt
...
...
...
LOG_20150119231500.txt
LOG_20150119233001.txt
LOG_20150119234500.txt
```

Comment: You should post the code you have tried.

Comment: Hi Jason, I don't have any codes yet. Will you be able to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this searches a range of one month. Adapt to your needs.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM generate list with all expected files:
REM omitting the seconds, as they are more or less random
(for /l %%d in (1,1,31) do (
  set d=0%%d
  set d=!d:~-2!
  for /l %%h in (0,1,23) do (
    set h=0%%h
    set h=!h:~-2!
    for %%m in (00 15 30 45) do (
      echo Log_201501!d!!h!%%m
        REM generate files with some missing:
        REM for testing; you don't need the following line:
        if !random! geq 500 break>Log_201501!d!!h!%%m00.txt
    )
  )
))>should.txt

REM generate list with all existing files:
(for /f %%i in ('dir /on /b LOG_2015*.txt') do (
  REM deleting the seconds also to be comparable
  set i=%%i
  echo !i:~0,16!
))>is.txt

echo expected files:
find /c "Log_2015" should.txt
echo/
echo found files:
find /c "Log_2015" is.txt
echo/
echo these files are missing:
findstr /v /g:is.txt should.txt
```

I'll leave proper formatting of the output to you.

**NOTE:** don't try this code on your logfile folder; it overwrites exisiting files (as I need to create them for testing)

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for your reply and help. Just wondering if it's possible to amend the script to check for a particular date only? Thanks. - Peter

Comment: of course. Just remove the loop for the days and replace `%%d` with your wanted day.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "lastdate="
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /o:-n /a-d "%sourcedir%\LOG_2*"') DO SET "lastfile=%%a"&GOTO scan
:scan
SET "today=%lastfile:~4,8%"
SET "lastfile=%lastfile:~4,12%"
SET /a yesterday=today
:: subtract 1 day from today. if last 2 digits are 00, -68=yyyymm32
:: keep subtracting until logfile found to cater for short months.
:prevday
SET /a yesterday -=1
IF %yesterday:~-4%==0100 SET /a yesterday -=8868&GOTO prevday
IF %yesterday:~-2%==00 SET /a yesterday -=68&GOTO prevday
IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\LOG_%yesterday%*" GOTO prevday
FOR %%a IN (expected found missing) DO SET /a %%a=0
FOR /L %%h IN (100,1,123) DO FOR %%m IN (00,15,30,45) DO CALL :check %yesterday% %%h%%m
SET "reportline=Yesterday %yesterday% expected %expected% found %found% missing %missing%"
FOR %%a IN (expected found missing) DO SET /a %%a=0
FOR /L %%h IN (100,1,123) DO FOR %%m IN (00,15,30,45) DO CALL :check %today% %%h%%m
ECHO %reportline%
ECHO Today     %today% expected %expected% found %found% missing %missing%
ECHO Last filedatetime found %lastfile%

GOTO :EOF

:check
SET checkstamp=%2
SET checkstamp=%1%checkstamp:~-4%
IF x%checkstamp% gtr x%lastfile% GOTO :EOF
SET /a expected +=1
IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\LOG_%checkstamp%*" (SET /a found +=1
 ) ELSE (SET /a missing+=1
 ECHO Missing : %checkstamp%)

GOTO :eof
```

I'm reasonably sure this will report appropriately. You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The name of the latest logfile is found by reading the directory for matching names, sorting in reverse-name order and selecting the first name returned.

"today" is determined by selecting the 12 characters from that name, starting at "character 4" (counting the 1st as "character 0")

"yesterday" is determined by subtracting 1 from that date. If the resultant string ends "0100" then subtract 8868 to form Dec. 32nd in the previous year, otherwise if "today" ends "00", subtract 68 to obtain the 32nd of the previous month.
If there is no log file for the date calculated as "yesterday", found by stringing "LOG_" before the value in "yesterday" and checking for any filename starting with that string, then keep subtracting 1 from yesterday until a filename is found. In this way, "Feb 31st" won't be found, nor 30th, nor 29th (probably) but 28th will be found for instance. SO Today=Mar 1st, yesterday=Feb28th or 29th.

Then it's just a matter of checking for a filename starting "LOG_YYYYMMDDHHQQ" - YYYYMMDD is in `today` or `yesterday`, HH is 00..23 and QQ is 00,15,30 or 45. Having the hour in `%%h` iterated from 100 to 123 and then strung with the minutes digit means the second parameter supplied to the subroutine `check` is of the form `10000`..`12345` in 15-minute steps. Lop off the leading `1` and string the result to 'LOG_'+the relevant day and check for a file that starts with that string. Either it's there or not.

The twist is that if the date+time to be checked for is later than the last date+time (in `lastfile`) then it's a future filename (eg 5pm today, but it's only lunchtime now) so we simply skip the check and counting.

The real kink here is that the values to be compared are >2147483647 so we have to force `if` into alphabetic mode by including a non-numeric in the strings to be compared.

Example:

```
 Directory of U:\sourcedir\t w o

21/01/2015  14:49                 0 log_20150120230016.txt
21/01/2015  14:49                 0 log_20150121011501.txt
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   2,126,053,376 bytes free
```

Directory list showing two logfile names in the specified format. The latest is `log_20150121011501` which is "today": 20150121 at 0115. The other is for "yesterday": 20150120 at 2300.

Normally, 4*24=96 files are produced in 1 day. This should hold for any day other than **today**. Only one file is present for yesterday, so 95 are missing.

For today, we can only be sure that the logfiles have been created as far as 01:15. We may be running this at 01:17, so it's perfectly reasonable to expect to **not** have today's files after 01:15. That would be 6 files for today (0000, 0015, 0030, 0045, 0010, 0015). 1 is present, 5 are missing.

The results from this procedure are: (no point in listing them all)

```
...
Missing : 201501202230
Missing : 201501202245
Missing : 201501202315
Missing : 201501202330
Missing : 201501202345
Missing : 201501210000
Missing : 201501210015
Missing : 201501210030
Missing : 201501210045
Missing : 201501210100
Yesterday 20150120 expected 96 found 1 missing 95
Today     20150121 expected 6 found 1 missing 5
Last filedatetime found 201501210115
```

Since `201501202300` is present, it's not shown on the `missing` list.
of the 96 expected files for yesterday, 1 was found, 95 are missing (and listed)
Of the 6 expected files for today 1 is present and 5 are missing and listed.

The fact that the report is showing `2012215` means that there's some problem with constructing the filename, but you haven't reported the final lines which will display the dates calculated for `today` and `yesterday`. I still for some reason can't see the filenames in your directory, so I can't analyse them, either. The procedure relies on there being more than one day's logfilenames in the directory to calculate `yesterday`.

---

How many more times do you need to be asked to EDIT the requested data into your question, not add it as an "answer" to be deleted by the moderators?

How many more times do you need to be told that this procedure relies on there being at least two dates on the logfiles? Your latest list all has the same date.

How many more times do you need to be asked to provide the last lines of the report which would show the procedure's determination of the date for today and yesterday?

Here's a directory listing of your original logfile list. I deleted one file, LOG_201501190245.txt for a demonstration. Note that the list has files generated for both January 18th and 19th.

```
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 02F1-3000

 Directory of u:\sourcedir\t w o

21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118210000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118211501.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118213000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118214501.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118220000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118221500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118223000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118224500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118230001.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118231500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118233001.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150118234500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119000001.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119001500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119003001.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119004500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119010000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119011501.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119013000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119014501.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119020000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119021500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119023000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119024500.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119030000.txt
21/01/2015  16:22                 0 LOG_20150119031501.txt
              26 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   2,134,638,592 bytes free
```

Here's the result with times on Jan 18th between 01:00 and 20:15 edited-out:

```
Missing : 201501180000
Missing : 201501180015
Missing : 201501180030
Missing : 201501180045
... (edited-out : 76 lines)
Missing : 201501180030
Missing : 201501180045
Missing : 201501182030
Missing : 201501182045
Missing : 201501190245
Yesterday 20150118 expected 96 found 12 missing 84
Today     20150119 expected 14 found 13 missing 1
Last filedatetime found 201501190315
```

So - 84 lines reported for 18th, report says precisely that.
Of the 14 expected lines between 00:00 and 03:15, one is missing - 02:45, as reported.

It's important to cut-and-paste, not retype because batch syntax is specific and a single typo can cause chaos. All you need to do is to replace the directoryname with the directoryname you are using.

If you have further problems, simply cut the actual code you are using and paste it into your original question, with an appropriate sample of the results. Two or three "Missing" lines are sufficient, but the last 3 lines are critical.

Comment: Hi Magoo,

Thanks for your reply and help.

I've tried your script and it's giving below error.

**D:\temp>test11.bat**

T**he system cannot find the file specified.**

This is the dir path that I've set, but it can't detect.

**SET "sourcedir=D:\temp\test\t w o"**

How should it be set correctly?

Appreciate for your help.

Thanks.


- Peter

Comment: `U:\sourcedir\t w o` is simply a test directory that I use which deliberately includes spaces in the name to ensure spaces would be processed correctly if used. You just need to substitute the name of the directory in which your log files are present. As you see, posting a comment as an "answer" produces a nonsense result. It's discouraged - some poor members are obsessed with finding and flagging non-answers, so best to delete them afore the *polizei* arrive. Also signatures and waffle are frowned upon.

Comment: Hi Magoo, thanks for the reply. I've set the path to SET "sourcedir=D:\temp\logs" but there is no output. It's only showing a blank screen and the script seems to be running with no output. Please advice. Thanks. Peter

Comment: I can't see into your directory from here. The script assumes that you have today's logs and yesterday's logs in that directory. That way, it can check today (so far) and all of yesterday. If a previous day's files are not present, it will keep looking back over and over until it eventually reaches today again - and that might just take a while. Try a directory containing at least 2 different days' files.

Comment: Hi Magoo, got it. Thanks for your help. I was doing some testing. This time, I just placed all the current files into 1 dir, no yesterday's files. Here are some of the output: Missing : 2012115
Missing : 2012130
Missing : 2012145
Missing : 2012200
Missing : 2012215
Missing : 2012230

Comment: Hi Magoo, think the date format for these missing files are not correct. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Magoo, I've provided some samples of the format of the filenames from 2 days ago. This is to show you how the log file format looks like. Is this OK? Thanks. Peter

Comment: Hi Magoo, I got a little bit confused on the way replies are being posted in this forum. Also, if I reply using "add comment" option, there are format limitation and I can't post the coding or sample data. Thanks. Peter